# Running android emulator for games in a windows 10 VM on a windows 10 host

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, android

I am trying to get a setup where I'm running a game that is FAIRLY gpu intensive on an android VM within a VM on my local machine.  I've looked into options like Virtualbox / VMWare Workstation, but neither have the option to allow for GPU (GTX1080) emulation that can handle the load.  I have a powerful machine that should be able to handle this kind of thing from a computational standpoint (AMD 3900x, 64 gb of ddr5 ram) but I'm just not sure what I should be using in terms of VM to make this work.

I've tried VirtualBox -> Windows 10(1809) -> Nox 6.6.1.1 without any success.

Any recommendations or settings that might need to be enabled other than the normal hyper-v or bios options would be useful.

I started looking into QEmu but it didn't seem like there was a good strategy for this as there wasn't persistent storage for created VM's

Comment: VirtualBox, Hyper-V, not VMWare Workstation supports DX12.  What you want requires VT-d or AMDs equivalent but you provided zero information about your processor.  I am taking this question as a question seeking a software recommendation which is out of scope

Comment: Running a virtual environment (Android emulator) within a virtual environment (Windows in VirtualBox) is always a bad idea. Device mapping from host to guest (GPU) may work on one level but I don't think that this has been designed for passing two virtual layers.

Comment: @Ramhound - " but you provided zero information about your processor" "(AMD 3900x, 64 gb of ddr5 ram)" ??

Comment: @A_Elric - I am not one hundred percent familiar with that particular processor.  Does it support the AMD equivalent of VT-d ?

Comment: @Ramhound Yup, it supports AMD-V

Comment: @A_Elric - **AMD-V** is **VT-x** not **VT-d**. **AMD-V** allows for hardware virtualization which doesn't necessary allow the use of the GPU within a VM.